# Parse Network connection failed

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

When i run my app the view loads with no data and it logs

> Network Connection Failed. Making attempt 1 after sleeping 7.22400 seconds

and after a few second it logs

> "[Error]: The network connection was lost. (cod 100, Version:1.7.2)

But i am Connected to the internet!

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday, I had the same issue and spent 2 hours. Then finally restart the machine and run the code worked for me.